# How to style text annotation using CSS in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, shiny, shinyjs, r-highcharter

I have below interactive plot using `highchart` `js` library with `R`

```
library(highcharter)
set.seed(100)

Data = data.frame(x = round(rnorm(20) * 100, 2), y = round(rnorm(20) * 100, 2), z = letters[1:20])
hchart(Data, "scatter", hcaes(x, y))  %>%
hc_annotations(list(labelOptions = list(y = 35, x = 0, backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', borderColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"),
                    labels = list(list(point = list(x = 71, y = 55, xAxis = 0, yAxis = 0),
                                        style = list(color = '#6f6f6f', fontSize = 8),
                                        useHTML = TRUE,
                                        text = "<span style = 'width: 120px; height: 120px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5)'>AAAA</span>"))))
```

I wanted to style the text-annotation with `HTML/CSS` styling. But having that in above code, I see the `tooltips` are falling behind the text therefore not clearly visible. However if I put `useHTML = FALSE` then I cant apply `CSS` styling with the text. Is there any way to bring `tooltip` front to give higher priority for visualisation?

@raf18seb added that we should add - `hc_tooltip(outside = TRUE)`

But, if we add this and use `highchart` within a `Shiny-app` then `tooltips` become invisible. Below is such an `App` -

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")
library(shinyjs)

Data1 = structure(list(x = c(15, 21, 71, 39, 34, -47, 67, 5, 1, -41, 
41, 6, 52, 84, 10, 67, -53, 15, 21, 51), y = c(-7, 75, 100, -67, 
52, 100, 100, -200, 0, -100, 28, 19, 100, 35, 39, 24, -73, 100, 
29, 81), z = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", 
"k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(id = "Click", style = "height: 500px; width: 500px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4)", HTML("Click Here"))
)

server = function(input, output) {
  onclick('Click', showModal(modalDialog(size = 'l', footer = NULL, easyClose = TRUE, highchartOutput("Result"))))

  output$Result = 
        renderHighchart({

            HighCharts_Plot =
                hchart(Data1, "scatter", hcaes(x, y)) %>%
                    hc_chart(plotBorderWidth = 1, plotBorderColor = '#b4b4b4') %>%
                    hc_annotations(list(labelOptions = list(y = 35, x = 0, backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', borderColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"),
                                        labels = list(list(point = list(x = (max(abs(range(Data1$x))) + 0)/2, y = 0, xAxis = 0, yAxis = 0),
                                                            style = list(color = '#6f6f6f', fontSize = 8),
                                                            useHTML = TRUE,
                                                            text = paste("<span style = '", "padding: 3px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4)", "'>AAA  AAA  AAA  AAA  AAA  </span>", sep = ""))))) %>%
                    hc_tooltip(outside = TRUE) 
            HighCharts_Plot

        })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any pointer what is the right solution will be high helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the Highcharts docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#html-in-highcharts

> *When useHTML is true, the text is laid out as HTML on top of the chart. [...] It (label with useHTML) will always be laid out on top of all other SVG content. Specifically the tooltip may be rendered below the useHTML label. Since Highcharts v6.1.1 this can be avoided by setting tooltip.outside to true.*

So the solution is:

```
hc_tooltip(outside = TRUE) %>%
```

**edit:**
In your shiny app, the tooltip is not "invisible". It's there, but under the modal box (visible when you hover over the point near to top edge).

When you set *tooltip.outside* to *true*, then the tooltip is renderer outside of Highcharts container (in your case, outside of *shiny-modal-wrapper* container). I don't know shiny so I don't know how to move tooltip container into your modal box.

**But**, I came up with this workaround. You can set the **tooltip.useHTML** to true instead of **tooltip.outside**. You need to disable a default styling and define your own styles. Below is just an example (Value: 7), but you can reproduce the same styles as the original tooltip has.

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")
library(shinyjs)

Data1 = structure(list(x = c(39, 15, 21, 71, 39, 34, -47, 67, 5, 1, -41, 
                             41, 6, 52, 84, 10, 67, -53, 15, 21, 51), y = c(0, -7, 75, 100, -67, 
                                                                            52, 100, 100, -200, 0, -100, 28, 19, 100, 35, 39, 24, -73, 100, 
                                                                            29, 81), z = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", 
                                                                                           "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                             -21L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(id = "Click", style = "height: 500px; width: 500px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4)", HTML("Click Here"))
)

server = function(input, output) {
  onclick('Click', showModal(modalDialog(size = 'l', footer = NULL, easyClose = TRUE, highchartOutput("Result"))))

  output$Result = 
    renderHighchart({

      HighCharts_Plot =
        hchart(Data1, "scatter", hcaes(x, y)) %>%
        hc_chart(plotBorderWidth = 1, plotBorderColor = '#b4b4b4') %>%
        hc_annotations(list(labelOptions = list(y = 35, x = 0, backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', borderColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"),
                            labels = list(list(point = list(x = (max(abs(range(Data1$x))) + 0)/2, y = 50, xAxis = 0, yAxis = 0),
                                               style = list(color = '#6f6f6f', fontSize = 8),
                                               useHTML = TRUE,
                                               text = paste("<span style = '", "padding: 3px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4)", "'>AAA  AAA  AAA  AAA  AAA  </span>", sep = ""))))) %>%
        hc_tooltip(useHTML = TRUE, padding = 0, headerFormat = '', pointFormat = '<span style="padding: 5px; background: #f7f7f7;">Value: {point.y}<span>')
      HighCharts_Plot

    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.useHTML

Comment: this solution is not working within a Shiny-app. Modified my post to highlight this issue.

Comment: This is really great approach. Thanks for such a workaround. Let me spend some time with this before close this.

Comment: Btw, any reason why behavior is different for Shiny-app?

Comment: Yes, I have described it in the answer ;) it is a part about "shiny-modal-wrapper". Shiny creates a modal window and tooltip is rendered outside this modal (in DOM)